# When using the Optional Luck Point rules, how does Skill Improvement work during the Investigator Development phase?

Tags: skills, call-of-cthulhu-7e

I just got introduced to this game and I'd like to understand some more of the how EXP and PC improvement is done.

So far I get that the more you use a skill the more you have a chance to improve that skill/skills or even gain new ones from multiple successful attempts. Now in standard play, you mark off skills successfully used during the session once no matter how often those skills are used, and at the end of specific amount of game time, you are allowed to attempt to improve those skills used individually.

However the Keeper uses the Optional Luck rules for his games. Now the rules for the Luck option is if you use Luck to modify skills rolls then you don't get a chance to improve skills at Investigator Development Phase. Now I'd like some clarification on this. If you use Luck Points to modify a skill or number skill rolls to pass the check, then during the next Investigator Development Phase, are you not allowed a chance at improving any skills successfully passed? Or just those modified by Luck Points?

EX: Game 3 - Investigator use Luck points to pass History, and a Drive check, but were successful with Firearms .45 Pistol, Jump and Natural World checks. After the game session is through and we're at Investigator Development Phase, do I get a 1d00 chance to try to improve Firearms .45 Pistol, Jump and Natural World and not with History, and Drive or I cant try to improve any skills cause I use Luck Points?

Answer (score 5):

From the Keeper book, Chapter 5 - Game System, Optional Rules:

> Also, no skill improvement check is earned if Luck points
>   were used to alter the dice roll.

As I have understand about the Optional Luck rules, what happens is that you don't check the skill you have used luck to modify the roll. If that skill was already checked, or if you use that skill successfully after, you check it and then proceed normally in the Development Phase

So, taking your example and extending it:

> Investigator use Luck points to pass History, and a Drive check, but were successful with Firearms .45 Pistol, Jump and Natural World checks. After that, he is successful in a History check.

In that cenario, the investigator can check the Firearms, Jump, Natural World and History skills, and in the Development phase he can attempt to improve them.